# Is there an event in the Excel JavaScript API that triggers when the name of a table is changed?

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-js

For an Excel add-in I am developing, I need to know when the name of a table is changed. The [“Events” section for Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.table?view=excel-js-1.11#events) does not have an `onNameChanged` or something similar. I’ve tried whether perhaps the name change is also covered by `onChanged`, but in the snippet below, it is not triggered by the name change of the table. The other handlers in the snippet are not triggered either. I’ve tested the snippet in Office Online and Excel for Mac (v16.39). Is there another event that is triggered when the name of a table is changed?

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const table = context.workbook.tables.add("A1:B2", true);
    table.load('worksheet');
    await context.sync();
    const createHandler = (name) => (async () => {
      console.log(`Received event: ${name}`);
    });
    table.onChanged.add(createHandler('Table.onChanged'));
    context.workbook.tables.onChanged.add(createHandler('TableCollection.onChanged'));
    context.workbook.tables.onAdded.add(createHandler('TableCollection.onAdded'));
    context.workbook.tables.onDeleted.add(createHandler('TableCollection.onDeleted'));
    table.worksheet.onChanged.add(createHandler('Worksheet.onChanged'));
    await context.sync();
    table.name = 'TestTable';
    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a bit more on your scenario, and see if there are some workaround that could unblock the scenario? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Office JS Excel API currently doesn't support `table.onNameChanged` event. In your gist, you try to use `table.onChanged`, however, `table.onChanged` only occurs when data in cells changes on this table.

Therefore, I would suggest that you could submit the request and upvote this request at [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563), kindly also share your scenario in this request.

Answer (score 0):

Given you would like an event fired when renaming a table made in Excel (not javascript), and that the presumed `onChanged` event on a `Table` doesn't fire when renaming, my hacky workaround is as follows:

Listen for the [`onChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#onchanged) event on the `Worksheet` (which holds `[Table]`) so that you listen for all tables data changes. When the event triggers, check `Table` in [`worksheet.tables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#tables)) for a change in name (compare with a `Map` of old names):

```js
const map = new Map();
worksheet.tables.forEach((table, i) => {
    const newName = table.name;
    const key = `${worksheet.id}-${i}`;
    map.set(key, newName);
}

worksheet.onChanged.add(() => {
  worksheet.tables.forEach((table, i) => {
    const newName = table.name;
    const key = `${worksheet.id}-${i}`;
    
    let oldName;
    if (map.has(key)) {
      oldName = map.get(key);
    } else {
      map.set(key, newName);
    }

    if (oldName !== newName) {
      console.log(`Name changed from ${oldName} to ${newName}`);
      console.log(`For table ${key}`);
    }
  });
});
```

On a side note: You can always listen for changes in Javascript by wrapping the object into a `Proxy`. Here is an example:

```js
let obj = {
    name: 'harry potter',
    age: 27,
};

// we want to listen for changes on name
// so wrap object in Proxy
obj = new Proxy(obj, {
    set(obj, prop, newval) {
        if (prop === 'name') {
            // put your changing logic here
            // or fire an event listener
            console.log("Name has changed");
        }

        // default behavior to store value
        obj[prop] = newval;
        return true;
    } 
})

obj.name = 'john smith';
// outputs 'Name has changed'
```

Read more about proxies here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will help me much. The `Table` object in JavaScript is already a proxy (`ClientObject`) for Excel’s internal representation of the table. The proxy's properties only become available after calling `load` and `sync` (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-core-concepts). I don't need to know when the `name` of the proxy changes, I need to know when the `name` of Excel's internal representation changes, which I think can only be done if it offers this as an event on the proxy.

Comment: I've updated my answer (as a workaround) to reflect your requirements. It does look like @raymond-lu is right about the API not supporting this feature. I'd even call it a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion involving `Worksheet.onChanged`. I've edited my question to include it in the snippet, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't trigger either when the name of the table is changed.